# Angular routing changing # from url

Tags: angular, angular-ui-router

I'm working with upgrading an AngularJs project into Angular 6. Earlier to open any page, I have used $state :

```
$state.transitionTo(stateName, {}, {reload: true});
```

Now in Angular routing has been introduced. I have made all required changes to open a page life-line-details page from a link added over the life-line page.

Changes are :

**app.main.ts**

```
export const routes: Route[] = [
    {
        path: 'life-line-details',
        component: LifeLineDetailsComponent
    }
];

@NgModule({
    imports: [
        RouterModule,
        BrowserModule,
        UpgradeModule,.....      
        RouterModule.forRoot(routes)
    ]
```

**life-line.html**

```
<td><a routerLink="/#/life-line-details"(click)="detailLifeLine(lLine)">Details</a></td>
```

**life-line.component.ts**

```
 detailLifeLine = function (lLine) { 
        this.router.navigateByUrl("/#/life-line-details");
    }
```

Also, I have trued navigate method. But won't worked.

life-line-details.html is a separate page should be opened from above actions and my project url should change to : 
**http://192.168.1.12:8080/#/life-line-details** but it changing to 
http://192.168.1.12:8080/%23/life-line-details

I tried to encodeURI and encodeURIComponent for the url passed to routerLink and navigate method. But none worked, I am unable to open the page due to %23 in place of #.

How can I resolve the issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In angular you just use the url as normal (without the hash upfront), if you want the router to use an hash infront of urls you need to use the [HashLocationStrategy](https://angular.io/api/common/HashLocationStrategy#hashlocationstrategy).

So you have to change `routerLink="/#/life-line-details"` to `routerLink="/life-line-details"`.

And you can configure the router like this:

```
RouterModule.forRoot(routes, {
  useHash: true,
})
```